# What is wrong with this method? (2)

Tags: java, for-loop

Not too sure where I am going wrong. I need to sum the first 16 elements of the series: 1, 3, 9, 27, 81.... using the method `total` The code does so by creating an instance of `Geometric1` that will be of typ Seq.

The `total` method prints a value 7174454.0 but i should be getting 21523360.

```
public class Geometric1 implements Seq{

private double b;
public static double result = 0.0;

public Geometric1(double b) {
    this.b = b;
}


public double valAtIndex(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Math.pow(b, i);
}

public static double total() {

    Seq s = new Geometric(3.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        result += s.valAtIndex(i);
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(total());}
}
```

Comment: 3^14 is 4782969.  That combined with the lower numbers may lead to your large number.  Besides the spurious assignment of "result" to a static variable (try making it a local variable by assigning it to the result to 1 and adjusting your loop's bounds to 1->16 (since you wanted the first 16 values)), I don't see too many issues with this code.

Comment: You're not actually getting that series, rather you're just summing the series of 3^i from i = 0 to i=15.

Comment: i am using `Math.pow` to calculate the `Seq s = new Geometric(3.0);` the 3.0 to the power `i` then summing up all the values. I know there are easier ways to work it out, but the question states that i need t work it out in this particular way using `Seq s = new Geometric(3.0);`

Comment: 3^14 alone is big, what are you getting?

Comment: I am getting 7174454.0 but i should be getting 21523360

Comment: You're not summing all the way to 15 then as your loop cuts out at 14 due to the conditional i<15.

Comment: anyway, your code look fine beside the fact that you don't init result parameter on each call before the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You just need to adjust your loop to run 16 times.

Keep result initialized to `0` (you've edited the post multiple times), and change your loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    result += s.valAtIndex(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be i <= 15, not < 15. That'll fix your problem. :)

7174454.0 is significantly smaller than 21523360.